# Is this a disease?

Tags: leaves, diseases, containers, foliage

I have planted a curry leaf sapling taken from a local nursery in a 10 inch pot in fresh store bought potting mix (cocopeat, perlite, vermiculite, sand, rice husk, vermicompost, neem extract). I put it in 3 hr sunlight the first, second and third days. Then around 4 hrs for two days and then 6 hrs yesterday (forgot to bring the plant). Since the fourth day or so, I am noticing black spots on the lower leaves as well as a sort of copper-orange colouration on the tips on some black spotted ones. Is this a disease to amend? Or just natural leaf stuff? The upper leaves are healthy.
[image]

[image]

[image]